# Jquery - dynamic remove droppable class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do battleship game. And I have a problem with draggable/droppable.
Please look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FS79e/2/).

If you take a ship from the right area and drop on the left, and then take another one you will see change class on area 1.

```
white - empty - droppable
blue - ship - should be not droppable
yellow - adjacent to ship  - should be not droppable
```

My code:

```
 $(".ship1").draggable({ revert: "invalid", snap: ".droppable",
        start: function(event, ui){ 
             ....
            for(var i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                if(playerArray[i].adjacent)
                {
                    var quickTpId = "#p"+i; 
                    $(quickTpId).removeClass('empty'); 
                    $(quickTpId).addClass('adjacent');
                    $(quickTpId).removeClass('droppable');
                }
                if(playerArray[i].empty)
                {
                    var quickTpId = "#p"+i; 
                    $(quickTpId).removeClass('adjacent'); 
                    $(quickTpId).addClass('empty');
                    $(quickTpId).addClass('droppable');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But this is not working. I can drop ships on blue and yellow area. That is no good.

Comment: where is droppable class in your css?

Comment: droppable is class create only for jquery. i add .droppable to css but still not working. - http://jsfiddle.net/FS79e/2/

Comment: Why are you not trying it with [`disabled`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-disabled) option instead of `addClass` and `removeClass`?

Comment: disabled works good. Thank you, now do somthing with target.event :)